# White Screen in Home Page

Tags: database

Initially I installed WordPress in my Linux Mint OS. It was working properly. Later I added another Database to the site. I changed `siteurl` and `home` value at `wp-options` table. I changed Database settings in `wp-config.php` file. There is no `.htaccess` file in my WordPress directory.

I am getting White Home page.

I am trying to debug using `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` and `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );`. I am not getting any error message also.

How can I solve the issue ?

Comment: was the site working before you changed the siteurl and home?

Comment: Thanks @Djave. Yes. Actually I changed Database and after that it is not working. Thanks.

Comment: you should change it back. Also what did you mean by added another database to the site? Are you trying to migrate a site to another server or change its URL? If so was there a reason you didn't ask how to do that? A white screen usually indicates a PHP error occurred and you can find out what that error is by looking at the PHP error log

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell. I am not migrating. Initially I installed WordPress in my localhost. After that I left default database and tried to attach another database to my WordPress site. I am getting White Screen while I am trying to browse Home page.

Comment: @TomJNowell. I used `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` and `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );`. But I am not getting any error messages. Thanks.

Comment: did you check your PHP error log file? Neither of those constants will display PHP errors in the browser. It's unclear what you mean by "attach another database" Do you mean you imported an SQL file from somewhere? Or do you mean you change wp config to point to a remote database server? It's extremely unclear what you mean, can you say it again but using normal standard wording? Be specific, use exact precise words that describe exactly what you literally did, even if it seems like you're talking to a 5 year old, avoid all ambiguity.